# Display decimal 2 places if float, and display decimal 0 places if int

Tags: javascript, decimal

I know how to do decimal 2 places.

use `toFixed(2);`   but the problem is all of number in list is always 2 decimal places.

I want to if fraction use decimal 2 places, if non fraction use decimal 0 places.

```
number     display
------     -------
1          1
3          3
1.341      1.34
1.345555   1.35
2          2
```

Comment: Check if the number is an integer or float, if float apply the toFixed(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function isInt(n) {
       return n % 1 === 0;

    }
    var num=3.00;
    if (isInt(num)){alert(num);}
    else{alert(num.toFixed(2));}
```

Comment: I think this is the perfect use case for a ternary operator : `alert(isInt(num) ? num : num.toFixed(2))`

Comment: You are right, but I love brackets, still have nightmares from python syntax..

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show(num) { // test for int is from duplicate question
  return (num % 1 === 0)?num:num.toFixed(2);
}

var nums = [1,3,1.341,1.345555,2],div=document.getElementById("res");
for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
  res.innerHTML+='<br/>'+show(nums[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```